# Deploying a Node.js project which uses Oracle Cloud database to Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, linux, oracle, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an application in Node JS which uses Oracle cloud anonymous database which is currently working perfectly with my application at local.
I wanted to deploy this app on Azure App Service and so I followed this [Microsoft Doc Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash) using this I was able to deploy my project and it is running on the server but unfortunately it is not able to connect to my oracle could database

while deploying I got some logs which says this

```
    ** Node-oracledb 4.2.0 installed for Node.js 14.17.4 (linux, x64)
 oracledb **
 oracledb ** To use node-oracledb:
 oracledb ** - Oracle Client libraries (64-bit) must be configured with ldconfig or LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 oracledb ** - To get libraries, install an Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
 oracledb **   https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
 oracledb **
 oracledb ** Installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
 oracledb
```

so from this, I somehow understood that I need to configure the Oracle client on a Linux server so after spending hours I got a solution where I need to set up the path here is the [Oracle Doc](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux) but even this settings did not worked for me still not able to connect it.
also, one more thing I noticed was as soon as I redeploy or restart my App Service the settings get vanished

for oracle, I have database name, password, connection string, and oracle has also provided me with waller.zip which has tnsnames and cwaller.sso

have spent 3 days understanding the problem, if someone can help with it would be great, please comment if you need any more details to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer (i.e. it's too big for a comment).

Start by upgrading to a recent version of node-oracledb, e.g. 5.2.

It sounds like you know what to do with the wallet files, but here is the node-oracledb doc on [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Databases](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionadb).  If you don't have the wallet files in a default location you can (with node-oracledb 5) use `initOracleClient({configDir:'/your/path'})` to indicate their location.

The final piece is to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of your Instant Client libraries.  Search for Azure doc on how to do this - I don't have experience with this environment.